# CloudReports (Cloudsim Extension) on Cloudlet migrations gives error Null Exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, migration, cloudsim

I'm Kind new in Cloudsim and CloudReports Extension so i don't know why
when running the CloudReports simulator it gives this Error:

nullpointerexception at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.power.powerdatacenter.processcloudletsubmit(powerdatacenter.java:269)

I was adding a cloudlet scheduling Algorithm to the Extension
All I can see that the error happens with cloudlets Migration.
I tried searching alot about how to Fix it but didn't find something that will help me.

the Error is like this:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Datacenter.processCloudletSubmit(Datacenter.java:761)
    at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.power.PowerDatacenter.processCloudletSubmit(PowerDatacenter.java:269)
    at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Datacenter.processEvent(Datacenter.java:159)
    at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.SimEntity.run(SimEntity.java:406)
    at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim.runClockTick(CloudSim.java:471)
    at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim.run(CloudSim.java:835)
    at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim.startSimulation(CloudSim.java:151)
    at cloudreports.simulation.Simulation.runSimulation(Simulation.java:157)
    at cloudreports.simulation.Simulation.runAllSimulations(Simulation.java:129)
    at cloudreports.simulation.Simulation.run(Simulation.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

plz Advise;
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while I was following the simulation examples provided in the CloudSim project. After debugging figured out that the problem was with setting the `UserID` of the created cloudlet. I was setting a random value as the `userId` while the simulation retrieves the cloudlet using the `brokerId`. So setting the userId with the brokerId that was created did the trick for me.

```
// dataCenterBroker is the instance of the broker which you created
int brokerId = dataCenterBroker.getId(); 

//setting the userId after creating the cloudlet
cloudLet.setUserId(brokerId)
```